# Stripping characters of a wxString

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, trim, strip, wxstring

I am working on an application written in C++ that primarily uses wxWidgets for its objects. Now, suppose I have the following wxString variable:

```
wxString path = "C:\\Program Files\\Some\\Path\\To\\A\\Directory\\";
```

Are there any ways to remove the trailing slashes? While wxString provides a `Trim()` method, it only applies to whitespace characters. I could think of converting the string to another string type and perform the stripping there and switch back to the wxString type (it is essential that I use the wxString type) but if there is a less convoluted way of doing things, I'd prefer that.

Comment: wxString.SubString(from, to) not what ou are looking for.

Comment: Very late at this point, but, after seeing all the feedback in the answers and comments, I have to ask: what are you using this for? Is it to pretty-print a path according to some rules you have, or is it part of further processing - composing valid paths from several elements, for example?

Answer (score 4):

The others have mentioned how this can be achieved using `wxString` methods, however I would strongly advise using an appropriate class, i.e. either [wxFileName](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_name.html) or, maybe, `std::filesystem::path`, for working with paths instead of raw strings. E.g. to get a canonical representation of the path in your case I would use `wxFileName::DirName(path).GetFullPath()`.

Comment: I'll take a look at this solution tomorrow and will update if it fits the bill.

Answer (score 2):

`path.erase(path.end() - 1);`

or

`path.RemoveLast();`

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would use, if I had no proper path-parsing alternative:

```
wxString& remove_trailing_backslashes(wxString& path)
{
   auto inb = path.find_last_not_of(L'\\');
   if(inb != wxString::npos)
      path.erase(inb + 1); //inb + 1 <= size(), valid for erase()
   else //empty string or only backslashes
      path.clear();
   return path; //to allow chaining
}
```

---

Notes:

- Unless you're doing something unusual, `wxString` stores `wchar_t`s internally, so it makes sense to use wide string and character literals (prefixed with `L`) to avoid unnecessary conversions.
- Even in the unusual case when you'd have strings encoded in UTF-8, the code above still works, as `\` is ASCII, so it cannot appear in the encoding of another code point (the `L` prefix wouldn't apply anymore in this case, of course).
- Even if you're forced to use `wxString`, I suggest you try to use its `std::basic_string`-like interface whenever possible, instead of the wx-specific functions. The code above works fine if you replace `wxString` with `std::wstring`.
- In support of what VZ. said in his answer, note that all these simplistic string-based solutions will strip `C:\` to `C:`, and `\` to the empty string, which may not be what you want. To avoid such issues, I would go for the [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library, which is, as far as I know, the closest to the proposed standard library filesystem functionality (which is not formally part of the standard yet, but very close).

---

For completeness, here's what it would look like using Boost.Filesystem:

```
wxString remove_trailing_backslashes(const wxString& arg)
{
   using boost::filesystem::path;
   static const path dotp = L".";

   path p = arg.wc_str();
   if(p.filename() == dotp)
      p.remove_filename();
   return p.native();
}
```

It's not as efficient as the ad-hoc solution above, mainly because the string is not modified in-place, but more resilient to problems caused by special path formats.

Comment: Using boost is cross platform and independent from wx.

Answer (score 1):

My use case actually also considers scenarios without trailing slashes.

I came up with two solutions. The first makes use of regular expression:

```
wxRegEx StripRegex("(.+?)\\\\*$", wxRE_ADVANCED);
if (StripRegex.Matches(path))
{
  path = StripRegex.GetMatch(path,1);
}
```

The second, as @catalin suggested, uses `RemoveLast`:

```
while (path.EndsWith("\\"))
{
  path.RemoveLast();
}
```

**Edit:** Using @VZ's suggestion, I came up with the following:

```
// for some reason, the 'Program Files' part get's taken out in the resulting string
// so I have to first replace the double slashes
path.Replace("\\\\","\\");
path = wxFileName::DirName(path).GetPath();
```

Comment: Regular expressions are massive overkill for this simple case, and the second solution is less than optimal because of redundant checks performed in the implementations of those functions (even though probably inlined, they're unlikely to be optimized away completely). I think there are better solutions, if you're still interested.

Comment: Yes, I always think there are far more better ways coming from you guys. I'd probably take a look at @VZ's suggestion later.

Comment: Regarding your edit: having to manually hack the backslashes before feeding the string to the path processing library defeats the purpose of using a dedicated library in the first place, don't you think? In this case, at some point in the future, someone could feed a Windows network path to that code (`\\server\share`), or, even more likely, an extended-length path, one that's not limited to 260 characters (`\\?\C:\dir`).

Comment: As of the moment, we limit the use case to paths of this form, as the input is not provided directly by the user. But of course, there are lot of input sanitation that we have to do.